# How do I check all values in a Spartacus shop using Cypress?

Tags: typescript, cypress, spartacus-storefront

I'm currently trying to test a shop in Cypress. One test is intended to test the usage of price filters. In my example, there are 4 filters that I want to click on one after the other. Then the first step is to ensure that the filters have been applied. However, I fail when selecting the filter. As long as I only choose one, the selection works.

I suspect it has to do with the asynchronous nature of Cypress. How do you do it right?

fixture file:

```
[...]

"priceRanges": [
    "$50-$199.99",
    "$200-$499.99",
    "$500-$999.99",
    "$1,000-$100,000"
  ],
[...]
```

DOM

```
<a
  routerlink="./"
  class="value selected"
  href="/electronics-spa/en/USD/Open-Catalogue/Cameras/Hand-held-Camcorders/c/584?query=:relevance:allCategories:584"
  data-cx-focus="$1,000-$100,000"
  tabindex="0"
  ><span
    ><span class="label">$1,000-$100,000</span
    ><span class="count">1</span></span
  ></a
>
```

This is what I tried:

```
  it.only('There shall be a way to filter products by price range', function () {
    const homePage = new HomePage();
    homePage.openProductCategoryLink('5'); // Camcorders
    // Stores, Price, Resolution, Brand
    cy.get('cx-facet').should('have.length', 4);
    cy.get('cx-facet').then((items) => {
      expect(items).to.have.length(4);
      cy.wrap(items[1]).children('button').should('contain.text', 'Price');

      // check for price ranges
      this.filterCriteria.priceRanges.forEach((aPriceRange: any) => {
        cy.wrap(items[1]).children().should('contain.text', aPriceRange);
        cy.log(aPriceRange);
        //  Price $50-$199.991$200-$499.993$500-$999.991$1,000-$100,0001
        // TODO: narrow the range and see if the filter is applied correctly
        cy.get(`a[data-cx-focus="${aPriceRange}"]`).then((linkFound) => {
          cy.log('Click on: ' + aPriceRange);
          cy.wrap(linkFound).click();
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

[image: There is only the last item checked instead all of them]

Comment: What is this returning `this.filterCriteria.priceRanges` ?

Comment: An object with 4 strings that are the price ranges strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks ok, forEach loops are a bit of a red flag but that one should work.

If you want to click all the check boxes, this should do it for you

```js
cy.get(`a[data-cx-focus]`)   // select all four ranges by not specifying the range value
  .click({ multiple: true }) // multiple items clicked at once
```

By the way, `cy.wrap(items[1]).children('button').should('contain.text', 'Price')` - do you have to click that open first?

---

Looking at the site, I think the forEach loop in the test is going too fast for the page refresh to keep up.

Try adding a check within the loop, say looking for the Applied Filter tags

```js
this.filterCriteria.priceRanges.forEach((aPriceRange: any, index: number) =>{

  cy.wrap(items[1]).children().should('contain.text', aPriceRange);
  cy.log(aPriceRange);
  //  Price $50-$199.991$200-$499.993$500-$999.991$1,000-$100,0001
  // TODO: narrow the range and see if the filter is applied correctly
  cy.get(`a[data-cx-focus="${aPriceRange}"]`).then((linkFound) => {
    cy.log('Click on: ' + aPriceRange);
    cy.wrap(linkFound).click();

    cy.get('cx-active-facets a')         // get the price-range tags under "Applied filter"
      .should('have.length', index + 1)  // wait for the correct number
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It was too fast. I had to add a cy.wait command.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress comes bundled with [lodash](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/_) which can help with the async nature of Cypress. You should push for better adding better selectors so your test is easier to read and maintain

```
// if you don't plan on using price ranges in other test files

const priceRanges = [
    "$50-$199.99",
    "$200-$499.99",
    "$500-$999.99",
    "$1,000-$100,000"
  ]

it.only('There shall be a way to filter products by price range', function () {
      // sectioncode stays the same

      // check for price ranges
      Cypress._.forEach((priceRanges: any), function(pRange){
        cy.wrap(items[1]).children().should('contain.text', pRange);
        cy.log('Click on: ' + pRange);
        cy.get(`a[data-cx-focus="${pRange}"]`).check();
        

        cy.get('.items-displayed').children('.price').each( p => {
           // code to check displayed items are within price range filter          
      });
    });
  });
```